# Using jquery-ui sortable method with connected scrollable lists, dragged item is misplaced during drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-sortable

The following Web page contains two jquery-ui sortable divs connected to each other.

Everything works great as long as the two divs aren't scrollable. But when I make them scrollable with:

#divLeft, #divRight { height:500px; overflow-y: scroll; }

the dragged item no longer appears under the cursor. Sometimes it's visible in the wrong location, and sometimes not at all (probably outside the scroll box).

Is there some fix for this?

Thanks in advance,

Jim

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <title>Jquery-ui Sortable Scrollable</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style>
  /*
  */
  #divLeft, #divRight { height:500px; overflow-y: scroll; }
  .ph {height:12px }
 </style>
 <script>
  $(function ()
  {
   $("#divLeft").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable", 
    placeholder: 'ph'
   }).disableSelection();
   $("#divRight").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable", 
    placeholder: 'ph'
   }).disableSelection();
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td valign=top>Left<div id="divLeft" class="connectedSortable" style="padding-top:10px">
   <div>Apples</div>
   <div>Oranges</div>
   <div>Bananas</div>
   <div>Peaches</div>
   <div>Plums</div>
   <div>Figs</div>
   <div>Dates</div>
   <div>Nectarines</div>
   <div>Strawberries</div>
   <div>Elderberries</div>
   <div>Apricots</div>
   <div>Crabapples</div>
   <div>Mullberries</div>
   <div>Calabashes</div>
   <div>Gooseberries</div>
   <div>Guavas</div>
   <div>JuJubes</div>
   <div>Coconuts</div>
   <div>Grapes</div>
   <div>Grapefruits</div>
   <div>Honeydews</div>
   <div>Prunes</div>
   <div>Limes</div>
   <div>Kumquats</div>
   <div>Lemons</div>
   <div>Olives</div>
   <div>Papayas</div>
   <div>Pineapples</div>
   <div>Pomegranate</div>
   <div>Pineapples</div>
   <div>Pumpkins</div>
   <div>Rhubarbs</div>
   <div>Sloes</div>
   <div></div>
  </div>

   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </td>
   <td valign=top>Right
  <div id="divRight" class="connectedSortable" style="padding-top:10px">
   <div>Blueberries</div>
   <div>Raspberries</div>
   <div>Mangos</div>
   <div>Watermellons</div>
   <div>Cantaloupes</div>
   <div>Cherries</div>
  </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233381/jquery-ui-sortable-connected-list-item-snaps-to-second-last-position  please give him the credit

Comment: That fixed dragging into the last position, but makes dragging between the two lists worse.

Now, when I drag from the left list to the right, the dragged item still remains invisible after being dragged out of the left list, and the left list itself goes blank.

Dragging from the right list to the left s slightly better, but the dragged item appears about 75 pixels below and to the right of the cursor.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a8ynjadc/  it seems to work fine to me. The stable version is out and I used the 11.1.4